# infinite loop carousel start from beginning after reaching end

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I tried to make an infinite loop carousel using vanilla js, I able to do so but looks like some problem in my animation.

when I reached the end of the carousel, it moved back to the first card, what the expected result is, rather than going to the first card, when the user comes next the first card will appear right after the last card, and the same case for the first card.
when use click or drag the previous in the first card it does not move to the last card instead it automatically moves to the last card.

Here is my sample code

```js
let container = document.getElementById("bannerCarousel");
let scrollElement = container.querySelector(".row");
let scrollCount = container.children.length;



//container.querySelector('img').ondragstart = function() { return false; };
class BannerCarousel {
    constructor(container, child) {
        this.slideContainer = container;
        this.slides = child;
        this.length = child.length;
        this.slideWidth = child[0].clientWidth;
        this.dragStart = 0;
        this.curActive = 0;
    }

    move(index) {
        let scrollValue = parseFloat(this.slideWidth) * index;
        if (screen.width <= 900) {
            scrollValue = parseFloat(this.slideWidth) * index - 60;
        }
        console.log(scrollValue);
        this.slideContainer.scroll({
            left: scrollValue,
            top: 0,
            behavior: 'smooth'
        })

    }

    prev() {
        this.curActive++;
        if (this.curActive >= this.length) {
            this.curActive = 0;
        }
        this.makeBulletActive(this.curActive);
        this.makeSlideActive(this.curActive);
        this.move(this.curActive)

    }

    next() {
        this.curActive--;
        if (this.curActive < 0) {
            this.curActive = this.length - 1;
        }
        this.makeBulletActive(this.curActive);
        this.makeSlideActive(this.curActive);
        this.move(this.curActive);
    }

    addDragEvent() {
        let _this = this;
        this.slideContainer.addEventListener("dragstart", function (event) {
            console.log("Drag start");
            _this.dragStart = event.clientX;
        })
        this.slideContainer.addEventListener("dragend", function (event) {
            console.log("Drag end");
            let end = event.clientX;
            let dif = end - _this.dragStart;
            console.log(dif);
            if (dif < 0) {
                _this.prev(_this.curActive)
                console.log("Go right");
            }
            else {
                _this.next(_this.curActive);
                console.log("Go left")
            }
        })

        this.slideContainer.addEventListener("touchstart", function (event) {
            _this.dragStart = event.touches[0].clientX;
        })
        this.slideContainer.addEventListener("touchend", function (event) {
            let end = event.changedTouches[0].clientX;
            let dif = end - _this.dragStart;
            if (dif < 0) {
                //prev();
                console.log("Go right");
            }
            else {
                //next();
                console.log("Go left");
            }
        })
    }
    getChildElementIndex(node) {
        return Array.prototype.indexOf.call(node.parentNode.children, node);
    }

    makeBulletActive(target) {
        let container = document.querySelector(".bullet-container");
        let bullets = container.querySelectorAll("span");
        console.log(bullets);
        bullets.forEach((ele, index) => {
            ele.classList.toggle("active", index === target)
        })
    }
    makeSlideActive(target) {
        this.slides.forEach((ele, index) => {
            ele.classList.toggle("active", index === target)
        })
    }

    addBullet() {
        let bulletContainer = document.createElement("div");
        bulletContainer.className = "bullet-container";
        for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            let bullet = document.createElement("span");
            bullet.className = "bullet";
            bulletContainer.appendChild(bullet);
        }
        this.slideContainer.parentElement.appendChild(bulletContainer);
    }
    addBulletClickEvent() {
        const _this = this;
        document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            if (e.target.className === "bullet") {
                let index = _this.getChildElementIndex(e.target);
                let scrollValue = parseFloat(_this.slideWidth) * index;
                _this.curActive = index;
                _this.makeBulletActive(index);
                _this.makeSlideActive(index);
                if (screen.width <= 900) {
                    scrollValue = parseFloat(_this.slideWidth) * index - 60;
                }
                console.log(scrollValue);
                _this.slideContainer.scroll({
                    left: scrollValue,
                    top: 0,
                    behavior: 'smooth'
                })
            }
        })
    }
}

let new_carousel = new BannerCarousel(container, container.querySelectorAll(".row"));
new_carousel.addBullet();
new_carousel.addBulletClickEvent();
new_carousel.makeBulletActive(new_carousel.curActive);
new_carousel.makeSlideActive(new_carousel.curActive);
new_carousel.addDragEvent();
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #0d3b30;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#bannerCarousel {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 1.5s ease;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    /* IE and Edge */
    scrollbar-width: none;
    /* Firefox */
    overflow-x: scroll;
    cursor: grab;
    @media only screen and (max-width:900px) {
        gap: 0px;
       }

}

#bannerCarousel::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

#bannerCarousel>.row {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50%);
    gap: 20px;
    flex: 0 0 85%;

    @media only screen and (max-width:900px) {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 100%);
        flex: 0 0 65%;
    }
}

#bannerCarousel .image-content img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 550px;
}

#bannerCarousel .text-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    
    @media only screen and (max-width:900px) {
     text-align: center;
     padding-bottom: 60px;
    }
}

.text-content h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: var();
    font-size: 48px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: normal;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.text-content p {
    color: #fff;

    /* D-UpWir-Subheading */
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 28px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    /* 155.556% */
}

.text-content a {
    display: flex;
    padding: 14px 40px 15px 40px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 10px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: var(--BB-Blue, #151E8A);
    max-width: 200px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: 700;
    @media only screen and (max-width:900px) {
       margin: 0 auto;
       }
}

.bullet-container {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 50%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    gap: 10px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.bullet-container .bullet {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.bullet-container .bullet.active{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container layout--fluid">
        <div id="bannerCarousel" draggable="true" class="container">
        <div class="row" ondragstart="return false;" ondrop="return false;">
            <div class="col-md-6 image-content" ondragstart="return false;" ondrop="return false;">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="Becel" />

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-content" ondragstart="return false;" ondrop="return false;">
                <div>
                    <h1>Title comes here</h1>
                    <p>Description comes here</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" ondragstart="return false;" ondrop="return false;">
            <div class="col-md-6 image-content" ondragstart="return false;" ondrop="return false;">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/301" alt="Blueband" />

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-content" ondragstart="return false;" ondrop="return false;">
                <div>
                    <h1>Title comes here</h1>
                    <p>Description comes here</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" ondragstart="return false;" ondrop="return false;">
            <div class="col-md-6 image-content" ondragstart="return false;" ondrop="return false;">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/303" alt="Country Crock" />

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-content" ondragstart="return false;" ondrop="return false;">
                <div>
                    <h1>Title comes here</h1>
                    <p>Description comes here</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" ondragstart="return false;" ondrop="return false;">
            <div class="col-md-6 image-content" ondragstart="return false;" ondrop="return false;">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/306" alt="Country Crock" />

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-content" ondragstart="return false;" ondrop="return false;">
                <div>
                    <h1>Title comes here</h1>
                    <p>Description comes here</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

codepen example is https://codepen.io/pranaysharma995/pen/LYqBpNO

Comment: Refer to [Bootstrap Carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/carousel/).

Comment: You need to modify your existing code to handle the transition from the last slide to the first one and vice versa. Do it by duplicating the first and last slides in your carousel, so when the carousel reaches the end, it appears to loop back to the first slide, and when it reaches the first slide, it appears to loop to the last slide.

Comment: The key issue in your current implementation seems to be in the prev and next methods of the BannerCarousel class, which need to be adjusted to create this effect. Your methods for moving to the previous and next slides (prev and next) should seamlessly wrap around. This means when you're on the first slide and the user goes to the previous one, it should smoothly transition to the last slide. Similarly, going next from the last slide should bring the user to the first slide. consider cloning the first and last slides and placing them at the end and beginning of the carousel